# Error building apk 'libraries must use the exact same version specification'

Tags: java, android

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:MaterialPreferenceLibrary:5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
}
```

***Error:***

> All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 8.3.0, 8.1.0. Examples include
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0 and
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty clear: You're using two different version of Google services.

This is 8.3.0:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
```

These are 8.1.0:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
```

Make them all the same version and it will work.

Note that both 8.1.0 and 8.3.0 are pretty old; Put your cursor on each line, click Alt+Enter and Android Studio will suggest you the most recent version:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

try this with your gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:1.2.0'
compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.18'
compile 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'
compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.1.2.1@aar'
compile 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:MaterialPreferenceLibrary:5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
```

}

Comment: App is getting crash if i use same versions on both.

Comment: Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: @SanadQaziTxt sorry for late reply can i know wether u getting the error after your implement multidex?

Comment: @SanadQaziTxt I'm not really suggest using multidex just keep it simple.But I know your situation the only way is to decrease the amount of dependencies you compiling. Check out which one you should use and which one you don't that the only way. Try to avoid using play-services:8.3.0 because it is massive.